# Save Button state after app exits

Tags: android, image, button, sharedpreferences

I have One button named six1.. i want to change image of the button when i click. after that i want to stay that image forever even if i exits that app

here is my code.. i have used preference but nothing works

```
public class Twentyeightdayspackmenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button six1;
    boolean clicked = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twentyeightdayspackmenu);
        six1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six1);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.mypck.asd", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
        editor.commit();



    }

    public void testclickok (View v)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.mypck.asd", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        clicked=true;
        if (clicked)
        {
            six1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day2);
            editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
            Intent bmi_intent = new Intent(Twentyeightdayspackmenu.this,bmi_activity.class);
            startActivity(bmi_intent);
        }
        else
        {
            six1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day1);
            editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);

        }
        editor.commit();

    }



}



Thanks in advance
```

Comment: In your testclickok your are not reading the value of `clicked`. You are setting it yourself each time.

Comment: Where are you reading your shared preference?

Comment: Please help with source code

Comment: When i click on button i want to change the button image ... after that i want to stay that image unchanged